# Download attribute is not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to use the download attribute, it works on Firefox but when I run the same HTML file in Chrome it does not work.

This is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Download</title>
  </head>
  <body>

      <a download="mylogo" href="san-francisco.jpg"><img src="san-francisco.jpg" alt="Photo" width="104" height="142"></a>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i dont think there is any problem with your code.. it should run on chrome

Comment: is that all the code you have? because it should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a target="_blank" download="mylogo" href="san-francisco.jpg" title="ImageName">
    <img alt="ImageName" src="san-francisco.jpg" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

If it wasn't for this:

download attribute:

If the HTTP header Content-Disposition: is present and gives a different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header has priority over this attribute.

If this attribute is present and Content-Disposition: is set to inline, Firefox gives priority to Content-Disposition, like for the filename case, while Chrome gives priority to the download attribute.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

HTTP-Header [Content-Disposition](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1)

Comment: I don't understand your answer, what i have to add to my code exactly?

Comment: Try to put target blank in <a>, target="_blank"

Comment: If it still doesn't work try to put your html file into a server like Apache using xampp control and so on. Because the download attribute is properly working through a server. Like this: <a download href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,PD94ANDSOON"><img src=' ' alt=' ' ></a>

Comment: For my case, the http header `Content-Disposition` is `inline;filename=log.txt`(`log.txt` is a fallback filaname), and the attribute `download` is `xxx.txt`. However, the downloaded filename is `log.txt` when I use Chrome(120.0.6099.129, arm64)